# sending http requests from android device to nodejs local server on PC

Tags: node.js, flutter, localhost

I'm trying to send http requests from my flutter app using android device to a local server on my pc and I've set the address of url to the actual ip address of my pc and also both my device and pc is connected to the same network but yet I could not complete the task and the app still not able to send any http request

how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate with the localhost on your machine and you are building your App on an Android emulator, on the android emulator, you must use: `http://10.0.2.2:{yourPort}`

Comment: I've got this error message      SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 36673    , does 10.0.2.2 is used only for emulators?

Comment: oh you are right, i edited my answer, sorry about that